# Where exactly Android Wear app Permission request to be placed

Tags: wear-os, android-permissions

I want to request the permissions that I need for my android wear app upfront as per [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-permissions.html). So Programmatically where exactly I should put my permission request code. Also is the protocol to ask for Permission the same as the mobile app like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 0):

All of the permissions are controlled in the Androidmanifest. Here is an example of some permissions being declared in the Androidmanifest:

These permissions are used to get the weather from the device and relay the information to an Android Wear device. Google offers documentation for developers to use to determine what permissions should be used. Declaring permissions should happen in the Androidmanifest in the format provided in the image. In the sample code posted, it is not necessary to include watch permissions, they are only required if the app works with Android Wear.

Way back in the day Google added a feature in Android 4.3 that let the user control what permissions apps could access on a per app basis known as App Ops. This was a great feature that cut down on privacy issues and gave users the piece of mind knowing that random apps installed could not access the device’s location. When Google introduced [Android 6.0 Marshmallow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), This time when an app needs to use a permission a dialog box pops up on the screen and asks the user if it is OK that the app uses a certain permission. This may get a little annoying, but at least every permission used by an app has to go through the user first.

If your app doesn't already have the permission it needs, the app must call one of the [`requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, java.lang.String[], int)) methods to request the appropriate permissions. Your app passes the permissions it wants, and also an integer request code that you specify to identify this permission request. This method functions asynchronously: it returns

right away, and after the user responds to the dialog box, the system calls the app's callback method with the results, passing the same request code that the app passed to `requestPermissions()`.

You should dynamically request the permissions from user on wearable devices just the same way you do on the phone side.